# close a div when a checkbox clicked with pure css

Tags: html, css, checkbox, show-hide

I am trying to close a div when a checkbox is clicked with css only not JQuery or Javascript but it seems not working properly. How can I adjust it?

```css
    div[id^="div-"] {
      display: block;
    }
    div[id^="div-"]:target {
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#div-1"><input type="checkbox" checked></a>
    <div id="div-1">          
         Here is the content. 
    </div>
```

How can I link the `<a>` click and the checkbox?

Comment: To help us identify the problem, and to get to the answer you need quicker, is there any additional information you could provide? What errors are you seeing, if any? What did you expect instead?

Comment: mark an answer as correct if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this with pure css would be to have the checkbox as a direct sibling to the div:

```css
#div-1 {display:none}
#checkbox:checked + #div-1 {display:block;}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
<div id="div-1">          
     Here is the content. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#text{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #text{
display:none;
 
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="checked">Click here<br>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only CSS you can do something like this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uckfcoeq/1/)

The + is the adjacent sibling selector, more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```css
#close + #div-1 {
    display: none;
}

#close:checked + #div-1 {
    display: initial;
}
```

```html
<input id="close" type="checkbox" checked />
<div id="div-1">Here is the content.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove the anchor and just let the input element because this trick that i'm showing needs elements in the same level or the second element be in lower levels of html structure.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<div id="div-1">          
     Here is the content. 
</div
```

css

```
div[id^="div-"] {
    display: block;
}


input:checked ~ div[id^="div-"] {
    display: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9693j8Ld/)